# Offering a different response in Dialogflow CX depending on previous interactions

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to set some routing in Dialogflow CX so that if a customer comes through and immediately says something along the lines of 'speak to agent' we first ask them what they're looking to do, to try and route them to the answer they're looking for within the chatbot. Then if they repeat it, we then give them some form of contact route, either live chat or phone. For example:

**Customer: Speak to Agent**

*Dialogflow: What would you like to contact us about?*

**Customer: Speak to Agent**

*Dialogflow: Thanks, we'll get you through to our Customer Service team *

This wouldn't apply if they've already asked a different question and then asked to speak to an agent as we've already interacted with them.

I've tried creating a response that asks 'What would you like to contact us about?' and then puts them through to the right question dependent on response, but it ended up looping. If I split it and try to put it through an intent first, it means I have some very similar training phrases in multiple intents.